# How to create 'calculated' fields at Waterline/Sails.js Model?

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

This is my Users.model:

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            minLength: 3,
            maxLength: 30
        },

        username: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
        },

        toJSON: function() {
          var obj = this.toObject();
          obj.link = sails.config.globals.baseUrl + sails.config.routes.user + obj.id;
          return obj;
        }
    }
  };
```

What I want is to use some attribute that is 'pre' calculated at the model. 
My solution was to inject the attr at the toJSON() function, but at the views I have to use:

```
<%= users.toJSON().link %>
```

There's a way to create a attribute or some methods to the user? Like:

```
module.exports = {

       attributes: {

        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            minLength: 3,
            maxLength: 30
        },
        myPersonalAttribute: function(){
           return "Value"   
        }
}
```

Comment: Your last example with `myPersonalAttribute` should work fine (missing `}` aside).  Have you actually tried it?

Comment: I tried, I put the }, but I didnt worked. says that myPers... method does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use attribute methods to return derived values. See my response to your github issue here: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/626#issuecomment-54192398

Comment: I agree this is correct, but isn't this what the OP says they are already doing and is for some reason not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            minLength: 3,
            maxLength: 30
        },

        myPersonalAttribute: function() {
            return "Value"
        },

        toJSON: function() {
            var obj = this.toObject()
            obj.myPersonalAttribute = this.myPersonalAttribute()
            return obj
        }
    }
}
```